# ERR: install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC

Tags: sql-server, perl

I am trying to connect to a mssql database using perl script.

My code looks as follows:

```
#!/home/fds/freeware/perl/bin/perl

use DBI;

my $user = "username";
my $pass = "password";
my $server = "server_name";
my $database_name = "db";

my $DSN = "driver={SQL Server};server=$server;database=$database_name;uid=$user;pwd=$pass";

my $DBH = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$DSN") or die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

When I run that script, I am getting the following error:

> install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC (@INC
>   contains:
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/FDSperl5.12-CPANmodules-5.12-20160408/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/FDSperl5.12-CPANmodules-5.12-20160408/lib/perl5
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/5.12/lib/site_perl/5.12.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/5.12/lib/site_perl/5.12.5
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/5.12/lib/5.12.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /export/fds/Linux_RHEL6_x86_64/lang/perl/5.12/lib/5.12.5 .) at (eval
>   3) line 3. Perhaps the DBD::ODBC perl module hasn't been fully
>   installed, or perhaps the capitalisation of 'ODBC' isn't right.
>   Available drivers: AnyData, CSV, DBM, ExampleP, Excel, File, Gofer,
>   Mock, Multi, Multiplex, PgPP, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge, Wire10, mysql,
>   mysqlPP.  at test_connect line 12

Can someone let me know how to proceed?

Comment: did you install DBD::ODBC?

Comment: I tried to install using the command:  cpan -i DBD::ODBC

But after installation when I verified if it installed properly using the command: "perl -e 'use DBD::ODBC;'" , I got the following error.
Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC 

So, can you please let me know how to install it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error got fixed when I exported the following environmental variables to the corresponding values: LD_LIBRARY_PATH & PERL5LIB

Comment: Can you share more detail on this like steps to export on MAC

Comment: Sorry. It's been more than 5yrs that I faced this issue and don't remember many details about it.